# How to split a String to an ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist, split

I know there is a String split method that returns an array but I need an ArrayList.

I am getting input from a textfield (a list of numbers; e.g. `2,6,9,5`) and then splitting it at each comma:

```
String str = numbersTextField.getText();
String[] strParts = str.split(",");
```

Is there a way to do this with an ArrayList instead of an array?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895342/java-how-can-i-split-an-arraylist-in-multiple-small-arraylists

Comment: @jhadesdev I think he/she wants to create an ArrayList from parts of a String.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create an ArrayList from the array via [Arrays.asList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-):

```
ArrayList<String> parts = new ArrayList<>(
    Arrays.asList(textField.getText().split(",")));
```

If you don't need it to specifically be an ArrayList, and can use any type of List, you can use the result of Arrays.asList directly (which will be a fixed-size list):

```
List<String> parts = Arrays.asList(textField.getText().split(","));
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't understand this at first but when I put it in my code I get it now. I don't think I understand my own question after you edited it though.. lol Oh well, that don't matter :D

Comment: I hope I didn't change the meaning. What are you unsure of?

Comment: I didn't know the split method returned an array... I wasn't sure of the first sentence but I think I get it now :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as a Split functionfor list, but you can do the split and then convert to a List

```
List myList = Arrays.asList(myString.split(","));
```

Answer (score 0):

We can split like below.

```
List<String> valueSplitList = Arrays.asList(myString.split(","));
```