# Java Stream: divide into two lists by boolean predicate

Tags: java, collections, functional-programming, java-stream, reduce

I have a list of `employees`. They have `isActive` boolean field. I would like to divide `employees` into two lists: `activeEmployees` and `formerEmployees`. Is it possible to do using Stream API? What is the most sophisticated way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to partition a list by predicate using java8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36678571/how-to-partition-a-list-by-predicate-using-java8)

Comment: @MalteHartwig note that duplicate *says* "predicate", but OP is actually asking about grouping by a function. I wouldn't reopen if it were closed as that, though.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

[`Collectors.partitioningBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#partitioningBy-java.util.function.Predicate-):

```
Map<Boolean, List<Employee>> partitioned = 
    listOfEmployees.stream().collect(
        Collectors.partitioningBy(Employee::isActive));
```

The resulting map contains two lists, corresponding to whether or not the predicate was matched:

```
List<Employee> activeEmployees = partitioned.get(true);
List<Employee> formerEmployees = partitioned.get(false);
```

---

There are a couple of reasons to use `partitioningBy` over `groupingBy` (as suggested by [Juan Carlos Mendoza](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46958213/3788176)):

Firstly, the parameter of `groupingBy` is a `Function<Employee, Boolean>` (in this case), and so there is a possibility of passing it a function which can return null, <strike>meaning there would be a 3rd partition if that function returns null for any of the employees. `partitioningBy` uses a `Predicate<Employee>`, so it can only ever return 2 partitions.</strike> which would result in a `NullPointerException` being thrown by the collector: whilst not documented explicitly, an exception is explicitly thrown for null keys, presumably because of the behavior of [`Map.computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) that "If the function returns null no mapping is recorded", meaning elements would otherwise be dropped silently from the output. (Thanks to [lczapski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11733759/lczapski) for pointing this out).

Secondly, you get two lists (*) in the resulting map with `partitioningBy`; with `groupingBy`, you only get key/value pairs where elements map to the given key:

```
System.out.println(
    Stream.empty().collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(a -> false)));
// Output: {false=[], true=[]}

System.out.println(
    Stream.empty().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(a -> false)));
// Output: {}
```

---

(*) This behavior isn't documented in the [Java 8 Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#partitioningBy-java.util.function.Predicate-), but it was added for [Java 9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#partitioningBy-java.util.function.Predicate-).

Comment: and third, the Map that you get is an optimized one internally, to hold only two keys.

Comment: I was curious about this: "passing it a function which can return null, meaning there would be a 3rd partition if that function returns null". I have created a code that return null `Stream.of(1,2,3,4).collect(groupingBy(x -> x == 3 ? null : x >= 3))` and after execution an exception was returned: `java.lang.NullPointerException: element cannot be mapped to a null key`. So it cannot be true.

Comment: @lczapski interesting, I'll update the answer. That's not actually [documented](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-), though.

Comment: @lczapski I guess this restriction comes implicitly from [`Map.computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-), which says that "If the function returns null no mapping is recorded".

Answer (score 8):

You can also use [groupingBy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-) in this case as there are 2 group posibilities (active and inactive employees):

```
Map<Boolean, List<Employee>> grouped = employees.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::isActive));

List<Employee> activeEmployees = grouped.get(true);
List<Employee> formerEmployees = grouped.get(false);
```

Comment: +1, but note that you should be *slightly* careful using this approach: the parameter of `groupingBy` is a `Function<Employee, Boolean>`, and so there is a possibility of passing it a function which can return `null`, meaning there would be a 3rd partition if that function returns null for any of the employees. The `partitioningBy` uses a `Predicate`, so it can only ever return 2 partitions.

Comment: I just did a little experimentation, and found there are other reasons not to use `groupingBy` - check out the edit to my answer. (Sorry, I'm definitely not just trying to rip your answer, I actually learned something by trying the two!)

Comment: @AndyTurner thanks. For this case I'm assuming that `isActive` won't return null (like it uses a primitive boolean).

Comment: I'd assume that is the case too. I'm just pointing out there is the *possibility* via `groupingBy`.

Answer (score 6):

> What is the most sophisticated way?

Java 12 of course with new `Collectors::teeing`

```
List<List<Employee>> divided = employees.stream().collect(
      Collectors.teeing(
              Collectors.filtering(Employee::isActive, Collectors.toList()),
              Collectors.filtering(Predicate.not(Employee::isActive), Collectors.toList()),
              List::of
      ));

System.out.println(divided.get(0));  //active
System.out.println(divided.get(1));  //inactive
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are open to using a third-party library, this will work using [`Collectors2.partition`](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/9.2.0/org/eclipse/collections/impl/collector/Collectors2.html#partition-org.eclipse.collections.api.block.predicate.Predicate-java.util.function.Supplier-) from [Eclipse Collections](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse-collections).

```
PartitionMutableList<Employee> partition =
        employees.stream().collect(
                Collectors2.partition(Employee::isActive, PartitionFastList::new));

List<Employee> activeEmployees = partition.getSelected();
List<Employee> formerEmployees = partition.getRejected();
```

You can also simplify things using `ListIterate`.

```
PartitionMutableList<Employee> partition =
        ListIterate.partition(employees, Employee::isActive);

List<Employee> activeEmployees = partition.getSelected();
List<Employee> formerEmployees = partition.getRejected();
```

[`PartitionMutableList`](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/9.2.0/org/eclipse/collections/api/partition/list/PartitionMutableList.html) is a type that extends from [`PartitionIterable`](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/9.2.0/org/eclipse/collections/api/partition/PartitionIterable.html). Every subtype of `PartitionIterable` has a collection for positive results `getSelected()` and negative results `getRejected()`.

Note: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections.

Answer (score 0):

An easier, cleaner way is using `stream.filter()` and `collect()` like this:

```java
activeEmployees = employees.stream().filter(Employee::isActive).collect(Collectors.toList());
formerEmployees = employees.stream().filter(employee -> !employee.isActive()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```