# Reordering numbers in an array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, indexing

I am trying to solve a leetcode problem :

Given an array nums, write a function to move all 0's to the end of it while maintaining the relative order of the non-zero elements.
Example:
Input: [0,1,0,3,12]
Output: [1,3,12,0,0]

And I think I have the correct solution but I'm just not sure why I'm getting it incorrect.

```
class Solution {
    public void moveZeroes(int[] nums) {
        for (int i = 0; i > nums.length;i++) {
            int j= i;
            while ((j<nums.length) && (nums[j]==0)){
                j++;
            }
            if (j<nums.length){
                nums[i]=nums[j];
                nums[j]=0;
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: `i > nums.length` in for-loop. That makes to never execute for-loop. It should be `i < nums.length`

Comment: Try with case like `0,1,0,0,0,3,12`

Comment: This is a partition problem, you can try a generic partition solution which might make the code more concise, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46958064/5698534

Answer (score 3):

You can solve this problem O(N) with one pointer. This'd pass through:

```
public class Solution {
    public static void moveZeroes(int[] nums) {
        if (nums == null || nums.length == 0)
            return;

        int pos = 0;
        for (int num : nums)
            if (num != 0)
                nums[pos++] = num;
        while (pos < nums.length)
            nums[pos++] = 0; 
    }
}
```

---

### References

- For additional details, you can see the [Discussion Board](https://leetcode.com/problems/move-zeroes/discuss/). There are plenty of accepted solutions with a variety of [languages](https://support.leetcode.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011833974-What-are-the-environments-for-the-programming-languages-) and explanations, efficient algorithms, as well as asymptotic [time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity)/[space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_complexity) complexity analysis<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms)</sup> in there.

Comment: The result is the same but you're not *moving* the zeroes as the task implies. You're just copying non-zeroes to the front and then inserting 0's at the end.

Answer (score 1):

The for loop isn't correct (has to be `i < nums.length`), also, your solution doesn't work if there is nothing to do:

```
    final int[] expectedArray = {1,2,0,0};
    final String expectedString = Arrays.toString(expectedArray);
    
    int[] nothingToDo = {1,2,0,0};
    moveZeroes(nothingToDo);
    assertEquals(expectedString, Arrays.toString(nothingToDo));
```

yields in:

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<[[1, 2], 0, 0]> but was:<[[0, 0], 0, 0]>
```

Just write some test cases yourself and see what's wrong.

In your case:

```
    if (j<nums.length){
            nums[i]=nums[j];
            nums[j]=0;
        }
```

is wrong because you're swapping `i` with `j`, even if `i == j` and `nums[i] != 0`.

Since I don't think you're asking for a working solution, I won't provide one. But here are my test cases:

```
@Test
public void testEmptyArray() {
    int[] array = new int[0];
    moveZeroes(array);
    assertEquals(0,array.length);
}

@Test
public void testZeroOnlyArrays() {
    int[] array = {0,0,0,0};
    final String arrayString = Arrays.toString(array);
    moveZeroes(array);
    assertEquals(arrayString, Arrays.toString(array));;
}

@Test
public void mixedTest() {
    
    int[] array = {0,1,0,2};
    final int[] expectedArray = {1,2,0,0};
    final String expectedString = Arrays.toString(expectedArray);
    moveZeroes(array);
    assertEquals(expectedString, Arrays.toString(array));;
    
    int[] nothingToDo = {1,2,0,0};
    moveZeroes(nothingToDo);
    assertEquals(expectedString, Arrays.toString(nothingToDo));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'for' loop should be: `for (int i = 0; i < nums.length;i++)`
then, your loop will run on the array indexes from 0 until it reaches the length of the array.

The current code will not even enter the loop as you have defined i=0 and the loop condition is run the loop only if it is larger than the array size: (i > nums.length) which of course is not true

Answer (score 0):

You are using `i > nums.length` that's why loop is not executed

You need an index for non-zero value. Here in my solution `j` is for non-zero  value index means when you find a non-zero value set `j` index and increment it. If `j` is smaller than `i` or equal that's means there will be zero found then set it.

```
  public void moveZeroes(int[] nums) {
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
      if (nums[i] != 0) {
        nums[j] = nums[i];
        j++;
      }
      if (j <= i) {
        nums[i] = 0;
      }
    }
  }
```