# How to divide a stream by object fields into two sets?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a stream, where each object is identified by a unique id.
Moreover, each object has a either positive or negative `Free` values.

I want to divide this stream into two Sets, where one contains the `ids` whose `Free` values was positive, and one with the rest.

But I find the following not being the right way, as I'm collecting into lists outside of the stream.

```
class Foo {
    int free;
    long id;
}

public Tuple2<Set<Long>, Set<Long>> findPositiveAndNegativeIds() {
    Set<Long> positives = new HashSet<>();
    Set<Long> negatives = new HashSet<>();

    foos.stream()
            .forEach(f -> {
                if (f.free >= 0) positigves.add(f.id);
                else negatives.add(f.id);
            });
            
    return Tuple2.tuple(positives, negatives);
}
```

Could this be done better, somehow with `partitionBy()` or similar?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java Stream: divide into two lists by boolean predicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46958023/java-stream-divide-into-two-lists-by-boolean-predicate)

Comment: Note that you can use [`partitioningBy(Predicate, Collector)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#partitioningBy-java.util.function.Predicate-java.util.stream.Collector-) in order to partition into sets instead of lists.

Comment: Side note: conditional expressions work in this case too: `foos.forEach(f -> (f.free >= 0? positives: negatives).add(f.id));`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can indeed use `partitioningBy`. You can specify what to do with each partition in the second parameter.

```
var map = foos.stream().collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(
    foo -> foo.free >= 0, // assuming no 0
    // for each partition, map to id and collect to set
    Collectors.mapping(foo -> foo.id, Collectors.toSet())
));
```

`map.get(true)` will get you the set of `id`s with positive `free`s, and `map.get(false)` will get you the set of `ids` with negative `free`s.

Comment: I was already typing in the same code, but you beat me to it ;)

Comment: That was the missing pice!

Comment: Unfortunately it's not possible to accept an answer right away. But I could now.+