# Convert List to a Map<Boolean, List> using Java streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Suppose I have below response class which collect response and some other data.

```java
class Response{
    Boolean status;
    String message;
    Integer id;

    Response(Boolean s, String m, Integer id)
    {
        status=s;
        message=m;
        this.id=id;
    }
    public Boolean getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(Boolean status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        id = id;
    }
}
```

List data as below:

```java
List<Response> response = new ArrayList<Response>();
response.add(new Response(Boolean.TRUE,"HelloTrue",1));
response.add(new Response(Boolean.FALSE,"HelloFalse",2));
```

I want result as two different list based on status type(`TRUE`,`FALSE`) using single `stream()` method.
e.g:

```java
Map<Boolean,List<Response>> responsesResult=response.stream().....
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java Stream: divide into two lists by boolean predicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46958023/java-stream-divide-into-two-lists-by-boolean-predicate)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can *collect* it using [`Collectors.partitioningBy()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#partitioningBy-java.util.function.Predicate-), this way:

```java
Map<Boolean, List<Response>> responsesResult = response.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(Response::getStatus));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Collectors.partitioningBy` method to split the list of responses into two lists based on the status value. This method takes a predicate as an argument and returns a map with two keys: true and false. The values of the map are lists of elements that satisfy or not satisfy the predicate. For example, you can write:

```java
Map<Boolean,List<Response>> responsesResult = response.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(Response::getStatus));
```

This will create a map with two entries: one with the key true and the value a list of responses with status true, and another with the key false and the value a list of responses with status false. You can then access the lists by using the map keys:

```
List<Response> trueResponses = responsesResult.get(true);
List<Response> falseResponses = responsesResult.get(false);
```

I hope this helps you understand how to use the `Collectors.partitioningBy` method.

Answer (score -1):

```java
Map<Boolean, List<Entry<String, Object>>> map1 = map.entrySet()
                                                    .stream()
                                                    .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(data -> data.getKey().equals("rate") && data.getValue().equals("1")));

List<Map<String,Object>> list1 = map1.entrySet()
                                     .stream()
                                     .filter(data -> data.getKey().equals(true))
                                     .flatMap(data -> data.getValue().stream())
                                     .map(data -> Map.of(data.getKey(), data.getValue()))
                                     .collect(Collectors.toList());

List<Map<String,Object>> list2 = map1.entrySet()
                                     .stream()
                                     .filter(data -> data.getKey().equals(false))
                                     .flatMap(data -> data.getValue().stream())
                                     .map(data -> Map.of(data.getKey(), data.getValue()))
                                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```