# Java - resize number of nested lists

Tags: java, nested-lists

I need some code sample or algorithm to resize `List<List<Integer>>` that should work in next way:

Let's imagine that we have next `newSize` and `incomingList` (pseudocode):

```
    int newSize = 4;
    List<List<Integer>> incomingList = List(List(1,2,3),List(4,5,6),List(7,8,9);

    List<List<Integer>> result = resizeListOfNestedList(newSize, incomingList)
```

`newSize` integer sets new size of `incomingList` and `resizeListOfNestedList` should return next result for non odd numbers (eg. 4):

```
    List(List(1,2),List(3,4),List(5,6),List(7,8)
```

and next if newSize is odd number (e.g 3):

```
    List(List(1,2),List(3,4,5),List(6,7,8)
```

`newSize` is always greater than `incomingList.size()`

I would appreciate any advice.

**Update**

With help of `google.common.Lists`, I have finished draft code (yeah, it smells), I hope it will help somebody.

In my case method receives different `incomingList.size()`s and `newSize` params and it's obvious that `incomingList.size()/newSize` will return double value (e.g incoming list.size() = 1000, but we need to "compress" it to 600 elements) so I am not able to use `Lists.partition` all the time. `expandList` is better to call after next code:

```
int maxSplitValue = (int) Math.ceil((double) incomingList.size() / newSize);

List<List<Integer>> firstPortionValues = Lists.partition(
      incomingList, maxSplitValue
);//size can be less than required after double to int upper round

if (firstPortionValues.size() < maxSplitValue) {
   List<List<Integer>> expandedList = expandList(firstPortionValues, maxSplitValue)
}
```

Results:

```
Incoming list:[[0, 1], [2, 3]] 
New size value: 3
Outcoming list:[[0], [1], [2, 3]]

Incoming list:[[0.0, 1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0, 5.0], [6.0, 7.0, 8.0]]
New size value: 4
Outcoming list:[[0.0], [1.0], [2.0], [3.0, 4.0, 5.0], [6.0, 7.0, 8.0]]
```

Code:

```
public List<List<Integer>> expandList(List<List<Integer>> incomingList, int newSize) {

        List<List<Integer>> resultList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int index = 0; index < incomingList.size(); index++) {

            List<Integer> nodeList = incomingList.get(index);

            final int minPortionValue = getMinPortionValue(
                incomingList.size(), resultList.size(), nodeList.size(), index, newSize
            );

            List<List<Integer>> portionResult = splitNodeList(new ArrayList<>(nodeList), minPortionValue);

            resultList.addAll(portionResult);
        }

        return resultList;
    }

    private int getMinPortionValue(int listSize, int resultListSize, int listElementSize, int index, int newSize) {

        if (listElementSize > 1) {

            int maxPortionValue = listElementSize % 2 == 0 ? listElementSize / 2 : --listElementSize;
            boolean isOkUseMaxPortionValue = maxPortionValue + listSize - index + resultListSize <= newSize;

            if (isOkUseMaxPortionValue) {
                return maxPortionValue;
            } else {
                return getMinPortionValue(listSize, resultListSize, listElementSize - 1, index, newSize);
            }
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    private List<List<Integer>> splitNodeList(List<Integer> nodeList, int minSplitValue) {

        List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>();

        if (minSplitValue > 0) {

            result.addAll(Lists.partition(nodeList, minSplitValue));

            return result;
        } else {

            result.add(nodeList);

            return result;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: @eltabo If I had some useful code-drafts, I would have posted it with question. Please note that I didn't ask for complete solution. Also, I suppose that there should be some java libs that can help.

Comment: task is not clear enough, didn't you lost value 9 in example ?

Comment: When you talk about handling a list of lists... this is basically a [tree](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522454/java-tree-data-structure), you might want to implement your datastructure accordingly. It can save you alot of headache. Then this becomes a more common tree traversal/rebalancing problem.

Comment: @unpc you should post an answer and mark your question as resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just code it, pure Java7. This code keeps new list of lists balanced, adding extra elements in the end.

```
public List<List<Integer>> resizeListOfNestedList(int newSize, List<List<Integer>> data) {

    ArrayList<Integer> allElements = new ArrayList<>();

    for (List<Integer> integers : data) {
        allElements.addAll(integers);
    }

    int elementsPerItem = allElements.size() / newSize;
    int extraElements  = allElements.size() % newSize;
    int indexToStartAddExtraElement = newSize - extraElements;

    ArrayList<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<>(newSize);
    Iterator<Integer> iterator = allElements.iterator();

    for (int i = 0; i < newSize; i++){

        int currentItemElementsCount = elementsPerItem;

        if (i >= indexToStartAddExtraElement)
            currentItemElementsCount++;

        ArrayList<Integer> current = new ArrayList<>(currentItemElementsCount);

        for (int j = 0; j < currentItemElementsCount; j++){
            current.add(iterator.next());
        }

        result.add(current);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you not use `ListUtils.union(list1,list2);` from [Apache Commons](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/ListUtils.html) and

[Java: how can I split an ArrayList in multiple small ArrayLists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895342/java-how-can-i-split-an-arraylist-in-multiple-small-arraylists)

Comment: Thank you for response. In my case I don't know chunk size. e.g method receives array size 1000 and requirement that nested list size should be 600 elements. If you try to calc chunks you will get double `1,66` which can not be passed to  `partition(List<T> list, int size)`. That is why I rounded chunks to upper value, divided, and then expanded to the size required.

Answer (score 0):

Reading your question, I can come up with the algorithm idea of doing 2 steps:

1. Combine all the sublist into one list (using [Guava Iterables](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#concat(java.lang.Iterable...)))
2. Partition the result of step 1 (using [Guava partition](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release09/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#partition(java.util.List,%20int)))

Guava helps focusing more in what we need than how to do it, therefore is easy to translate your pseudo code and working code.

So, you can have something like this:

```
@Test
public void test(){
    // Init lists
    List<Integer> a = Lists.newArrayList(1,2,3);
    List<Integer> b = Lists.newArrayList(4,5,6);
    List<Integer> c = Lists.newArrayList(7,8,9);

    List<List<Integer>> incomingList = Lists.newArrayList(a,b,c);
    System.out.println(incomingList);

    // Create combined list
    Iterable<Integer> tempList = Iterables.concat(incomingList);

    // Re-Partition list 
    Iterable<List<Integer>> result = Iterables.partition(tempList, 2); // New size: 2

    // Convert from Iterables to List
    List<List<Integer>> finalList = Lists.newArrayList(result);
    System.out.println(finalList);
}
```

The output is:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]      // Incoming list
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [9]]  // Final list
```

Above code is to debug easily, you can reduce the code in less lines and also leverage import static to make it more readable and having this:

```
import static com.google.common.collect.Iterables.*;
import static com.google.common.collect.Lists.*;

public void test(){
    List<Integer> a = newArrayList(1,2,3);
    List<Integer> b = newArrayList(4,5,6);
    List<Integer> c = newArrayList(7,8,9);

    List<List<Integer>> incomingList = newArrayList(a,b,c);
    System.out.println(incomingList);

    // Repartition
    List<List<Integer>> finalList = newArrayList(partition(concat(incomingList), 2));
    System.out.println(finalList);
}
```

As a note on the result list, partition method create multiple lists of N values but the last list can have less values. For what you stated seems you want the less values at the beginning. I leave that to you to search partition methods and guava usages.