# How can I split an ArrayList of type string into 5 different subArrays without using guava or any external Library?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Currently the code I have adds a set of attributes into the list below, and returns one giant ArrayList with 70 attributes. I'd like those 70 attributes split into 5 Arrays that represent the 5 columns of the dataset - so I can more easily visualise and then compare the data repetition inside each.

I cannot use an external library like guava since its for an assignment so I can't add any extra files into the project.

I found methods that only work to partition byte lists, and a List<> generic method which I could not make work.

Any suggestions? I know this should be so simple but I cannot find the solution

```
ArrayList<String> allRows = new ArrayList<String>();


        for (int ex = 1; ex < dataExamples; ex++) {
            for( int ats = 0; ats < dataAttributes; ats++){

                allRows(data[ex][ats]);



                        }       
                }   
        System.out.println(allRows);
```

Comment: Why don't you build an object with the correlated values, instead of arranging them as flying values correlated with some other data structures? Something like: `Example { row1, row2, row3 ... rowN }` — eventually, `rowX` is a meaningful name, I just used them because I don't know what your column names may look like. Then you can make an array of `Example` and you have everything packed up ready for (almost) anything...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a simple problem of iterating through the data in the correct manner.

I am unsure if you want Horizontal insertion into the 2d array or vertical insertion. So I've added both, just uncomment the one you want.

```
// Create fake data
ArrayList<Integer> allRows = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i < 70; i++)
  allRows.add(i);

System.out.printf("All Data: %s%n", allRows.toString());

// Create 2 Dementional Array
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> twoDRows = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
// Add the 5 rows
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    twoDRows.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());

// Split allRows
for (int i = 0; i<allRows.size(); i++) {
  int rowToAddTo;

  // Horizontal
  rowToAddTo = i/(allRows.size()/twoDRows.size());

  // Vertical
  rowToAddTo = i%twoDRows.size();

  twoDRows.get(rowToAddTo).add(allRows.get(i));
}

// Pretty-ish print
for (ArrayList<Integer> array:twoDRows)
  System.out.println(array);
```

Comment: Brilliant Aaron, I just changed the types to String and that seemed to do it! Cheers

Comment: good, its the same as what I answered, use the mod operation and determine which array to use

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your array contains your column elements evenly distributed (that is elements 0,5,10,... belong to the same column; 1,6,11,.. to another column, etc.) you can use the **mod** operation (`%`) to separate those elements, something like this:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> listOfLists = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

//populate listOfLists
for(int i = 0; i < numberOfColumns; i++){
    listOfLists.add(new ArrayList<String>());
}

for(int index = 0; index < totalElements; index++){
    //Obtain number of correponding column with mod
    int remainder = index % numberOfColumns;

    //Insert your element into that corresponding array in listOfLists
    listOfLists.get(remainder).add("YOUR ELEMENT");        
}
```

Notice that `numberOfColumns` is the total number of columns you have, being it 5 or something else.

You may also want to check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895342/java-how-can-i-split-an-arraylist-in-multiple-small-arraylists) answer regarding the `sublist()` method. Which seems to be also similar to your question.

Cheers

**EDIT**
Changed the code so it will match any number of columns and add your element to the corresponding array.

Comment: Thanks GrayCygnus - but the problem is that the data i'm reading is always changing - I have a variable that stores how many columns there are in the file that the algorithm is reading (right now there are 5 for the dataset I am reading) so I want to split the data for the same amount of columns there are: ex while(ArrayNumber < columnNr) : create new sub array, with the size of columnNr

Comment: In that case you should check the question I linked in the answer, regarding the `sublist()` method. Either that, or make an `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>` with `columnNr` elements, each one corresponding to a column and use the **mod** operator to determine to which element of your Array of Arrays it corresponds.

Comment: I modified my answer to reflect what I am saying