# Dividing a Java List into sublists based on values

Tags: java, arraylist

Here's my list:

```
myList =
 ["HEADING","POST","POST","POST","CALL_TO_ACTION","HEADING","POST","POST","POST","CALL_TO_ACTION","HEADING","POST","POST","CALL_TO_ACTION"]
```

I would like to have some logic in place that would help me divide `myList` into below three sub-lists (stored as, say,  `List<List<String> subLists`):

```
["HEADING","POST","POST","POST","CALL_TO_ACTION"]
["HEADING","POST","POST","POST","CALL_TO_ACTION"]
["HEADING","POST","POST","CALL_TO_ACTION"]
```

Please note, the number three comes from the number of occurrences of the element `"HEADING"` (which I could find out using `Collections.frequency(myList, "HEADING")`).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: how can I split an ArrayList in multiple small ArrayLists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895342/java-how-can-i-split-an-arraylist-in-multiple-small-arraylists)

Comment: @ShubhenduPramanik I don't think it's a duplicate. The post you are referring is about subList creation with a specific length.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this is,

**Step 1:** Collect all the indices from your `myList` where "HEADING" appears.

```
List<Integer> indexList = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int index = 0; index < list.size(); index++) {
        if(list.get(index).equals("HEADING"))
            indexList.add(index);
    }
```

**Step 2:** Iterate through this `indexList` and create sub lists by using current index and the next index.

```
for(int builderIndex = 0; builderIndex < indexList.size(); builderIndex++) {
    List<String> test = null;
    if(builderIndex == indexList.size() - 1) {
        test = list.subList(indexList.get(builderIndex), list.size());
    } else {
        test = list.subList(indexList.get(builderIndex), indexList.get(builderIndex + 1));
    }
    System.out.println(test);
}
```

Boundary condition is to check if the current index is equal to one less than the size of the `indexList`. If yes, then the end index of the sub list would be the size of the original list.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I can't think of a way to avoid loops, since the sublists don't have a constant length. Apache Commons Collections 4.1 and Google Guava provide an easy solution in case of constant sublist length.

Comment: Yes, I've used as minimal loops as possible. The running time of this code would be `~n+m` where `n` is the length of original list and `m` is the length of index list.

Comment: Thank you @ShyamBaitmangalkar, your solution helps. I've modified it slightly to suit my requirement so that it gives me a `List<List<String>>` instead of `List<String>`.

Comment: @AkshayMaldhure, I'm glad that it's been helpful!