# Fill dynamically 2D array - Java

Tags: java, arrays

I can sequentially retrieve the following list of elements in Java and I need to insert them in an AxB dimension matrix. How can I put these elements in their order to the matrix?

```
Element: rainy
Element: hot
Element: high
Element: false
Element: No
Element: rainy
Element: cold
Element: normal
Element: true
Element: yes
```

My desired output is this:

```
array = [[rainy, hot, high, false, No],[rainy, cold, normal, true, yes]]
```

How to begin?

Comment: Have you at least tried to solve? Show us some code of what you tried.

Comment: Look for list partitioning in java. Check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895342/java-how-can-i-split-an-arraylist-in-multiple-small-arraylists

Comment: But I suggest you create a class holding related data. You could create, for instance, a class `Weather` or something, with fields like `precipitation`, `temperature`, et cetera.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not very clear for me, but since I cannot comment yet here goes an answer:

I am going to assume that you have your data in an array (like so `String [] dataset`) and want to convert it in a bidimensional array so here are the steps.

First initialize the bidimensional array with your AxB size:

```
int a = dataset.length/5; // the size of your dataset divided by the chuncks
int b = 5; // the size of your chunck
String[][] processedDataset = new String[a][b];
```

Then you want to fill in the bidimensional array with your dataset. This can be done with a basic for loop:

```
int k = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < processedDataset.length; i++){
  for(int j = 0; j < processedDataset[i].length; j++){
    processedDataset[i][j] = dataset[k++];
  }
}
```

Comment: `dataset[i+j]` should be `dataset[i*processedDataset[i].length+j]`. Another option is to use a third loop variable, `k`, initialized to 0 in the outer `for` loop and incremented in the inner `for` loop, then access dataset[k]

Comment: Thanks @SirRaffleBuffle, edited answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the guava library for partitioning
[Guava list partition](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/12.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#partition(java.util.List,%20int))

```
List<String> element= //...
List<List<String>> smallerLists = Lists.partition(element, # of partition you want);
```