# Create intervals of size N from a given integer

Tags: java, algorithm

Lets say I have an integer for example `6350` . How can I create intervals of size `N` (lets say 500) that results in the following ranges:

```
[0, 500, 1000, 1500, 2000 ... 6000, 6350]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java: how can I split an ArrayList in multiple small ArrayLists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895342/java-how-can-i-split-an-arraylist-in-multiple-small-arraylists)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most obvious java only (no third parties) solution:

```
int max = 6350;
int N = 500;

List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();

for(int i = 0 ; i < max; i+=N) {
    result.add(i);
}

result.add(max);
```

The `result` array list should look like exactly as you’ve posted in the question

Comment: 6500 is part of the result

Comment: Because Mark wrote `int max = 6530;` instead of `int max = 6350;`

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo, fixed

Comment: I like what you did at the end, add max :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use **IntStream**

```
    int limit = 6350;
    int interval = 500;
    int[] array = IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i < limit, i -> i + interval).toArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Using streams as a replacement of `for` loop:

```
final int MAX = 6350, INC = 500;
Stream.concat(
    Stream.iterate(0, i -> i < MAX, i -> i + INC),
    Stream.of(MAX)
)
.collect(Collectors.toList()) // may be skipped
.forEach(System.out::println);
```

prints sequence:

```
500
1000
1500
2000
2500
3000
3500
4000
4500
5000
5500
6000
6350
```