# I would like to display the colours in the list into two different groups like team 1 and team 2.How do i separate the array list?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I intended to create a program which randomly select students and group them into 2 different team.
Currently i manage to create output that displays random list but how do i group this output list into 2 different group

```java
public class Random {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        List<String> aListColors  = new ArrayList<String>();

        aListColors.add("Red");
        aListColors.add("Green");
        aListColors.add("Blue");
        aListColors.add("Red");
        aListColors.add("Yellow");

        //shuffle the list and get elements from it
        Collections.shuffle( aListColors );

        for(String color : aListColors)

        System.out.println(color);

    }
```

After Based on comments i have modified my code to this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    List<String> list  = new ArrayList<String>();

    list.add("Red");
    list.add("Green");
    list.add("Blue");
    list.add("Blue1");
    list.add("Blue2");
    list.add("Blue3");


    //shuffle the list and get elements from it

    for(String color :list) {

        Collections.shuffle(list);
        List[] lists = split(list);         
        System.out.println(lists[0]); 


    }

}

private static List[] split(List<String> list) {    

     List<String> first = new ArrayList<String>(); 
     List<String> second = new ArrayList<String>();

     int size = list.size(); 

     for (int i = 0; i < size / 2; i++) 
            first.add(list.get(i)); 

     for (int i = size / 2; i < size; i++) 
            second.add(list.get(i)); 

     return new List[] { first, second };   

}
```

but i keep getting multiple values and duplicated values...How to resolve it
this is the output
Blue3, Blue, Green
Red, Green, Blue
Red, Blue1, Blue3
Green, Blue, Blue2
Blue1, Blue, Blue3
Blue3, Blue, Blue2

Comment: after shuffle, you just have to spllit the list into two [Java: split a List into two sub-Lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379551/java-split-a-list-into-two-sub-lists)

Comment: Just initialize two other lists and put all elements with indexes less than `aListColors.length/2` to the first and others to the second